# Consider 2 seats in a restaurant ( lets say S1 & S2 ) and both the seats have an ongoing order ( lets say O1 and O2 ), I want to join the seats,orders

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am working on my personal project which is a POS system for a restaurant, and the table structure is as follows :

```
1.Table name : seats

Columns : 1) seats_id

2.Table name : Orders

Columns : 1) order_id <> 2) seats_id
```

**Every order is associated with a seat_id.**

Let us say we have 2 seats and 2 concurrent ongoing orders, but then the customers in both the seats are from the same family and they want to join the seats and place orders.

```
Scenario 1 : lets say we have no orders right now on the seats and we want to join them

Scenario 2 : lets sat we have ongoing orders on the seats and we want to join them.
```

I store all my ongoing and completed orders in the table `"orders"` which has ( `seat_id`, `order_id` and other item details ).

Should I create a temporary `seat_id` and then push it to my order table or is there a better approach to this.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "joining seats"? An order is per person, surely? do you mean you have 2 people ordering a meal to share? If so then orders>seats is a one-many relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to design reorganisation of seats and orders then I would try to not change all data in the database. Perhaps a mapping table fits your model?

```
Table1: Seats (seat_id)
Table2: Orders (order_id)
Table3: SeatsOrders (seat_id, order_id)
```

So "joining" means only changes of ids in SeatsOrder.

See
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d1070256d73029a44239201902342d13

Comment: I came back to post the answer of how I went on to solve the issue, and this is exactly that worked for me, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing an entity:

- Seats are physical spaces in your restaurant.
- Orders are a relationship between menu items and a seat, at a particular time.  The menu items are not part of this question.
- Bills are comprised of one or more orders.

It is that last entity that you are missing.  This should be implemented using two additional tables, `billOrders` and `bills`.